# how to install magento extension

Tags: extensions

I want to install this extension. I bought the source code from the company.

but here, what the install procedure of extension is confusing for me.

please search these following lines in above link :

"now unzip the respective marketplace zip you will find the app folder 
inside that move that app and skin folder in magento root as per the screenshot".

but when i try to copy "app & skin" to root of magento folder using "ftp[filezilla", we are getting "app & skin folders
exists, do you want to overwrite the files". So i am in confusion how to install this extension.

please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS do you use??

Comment: windows 7   ......

Comment: Ok then you can install Magento extensions or themes using Magento connect are you not aware of that procedure??

Comment: hi keyul, thanks a lot for editing this.... do you have any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: installing yourself without using magento connect makes more understanding about the extension and to keep track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes no  confusion, its simple.

when you install an extension with your magento, it better dont just copy and paste the extension to your magento.

Please follow this,

```
1.first unzip your extension.
2. compare its folder then find its equivalent folder with your magento.      
forex:
     I.if your extension has `app` then in your magento `magento->app`
     II. if your extension has 'skin` then in your magento `magento->skin` are the equivalent folder.
3.Until find equivalent folder,just traverse along with it, if you cant find in your magento , then create it in your magento.
4.Then copy the extension file, and before paste into the corresponding folder, check if your magento has a file with same name, if it does not simply paste it or else just compare these files and just copy the differing lines .
```

Thats all.This is what you should follow for all plugins.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i did the same , but after i installed using same procedure, i can not able to see the "my account section".

i really don't know what's wrong....

thanks a lot for clearing my confusion , because in that link, they did't provided properly.

Comment: Its coding based, maybe extension code have the problem or just check the correct layout file.

Comment: update with image where your `my account section` comes.

Comment: hi, the problemm  solved, problem is with extension.